# Failed to run TensorFlow inference

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have a problem with running my trained yolov2 network on android. I am using this project for my testing https://github.com/szaza/android-yolo-v2.

The provided network is working just fine. The problem only exists with my trained network. I converted my yolov2.weights file to a pb file using darkflow. I tried to find information on the type of error I am facing but my understanding of the inner workings of TensorFlow are too little to get what is happening.

It looks like the frozen graph is loading properly:

```
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded model from 'file:///android_asset/yolov2_finderpatterns.pb'
```

So I guess TensorFlow has problems with something else maybe someone can explain to me what this error means:

```
E/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Failed to run TensorFlow inference with inputs:[input], outputs:[output]
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: inference
Process: org.tensorflow.yolo, PID: 16974
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'ExtractImagePatches' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

     [[{{node ExtractImagePatches}} = ExtractImagePatches[T=DT_FLOAT, ksizes=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]](47-leaky)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in tensorflow repository, with a solution , please see [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10153#issuecomment-346284237)